# How to compare the effect of $X$ on $Y_{1}$ and $Y_{2}$, when $Y_{1}$ and $Y_{2}$ are correlated?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, residuals, partial-correlation

I have a single IV ($X$) and two DVs ($Y_{1}$, $Y_{2}$). All variables are continuous. $Y_{1}$ and $Y_{2}$ are significantly and moderately correlated. I would like to know if $X$ is more strongly correlated to $Y_{1}$ or $Y_{2}$ (or vice versa). What I *think* I have to do is to "control for" or "partial out" the correlation between $Y_{1}$ and $Y_{2}$.

First, I don't think I want a partial correlation, as that controls for the shared variance between the control variable (let's say it's $Y_{2}$ here) and *both* the IV ($X$) and the DV ($Y_{1}$). I only want to control for the shared variance between $Y_{1}$ and $Y_{2}$.

Second, I don't think I want a semi-partial correlation in a multiple regression, as that only controls for the variance shared by the IV ($X$) and the control ($Y_{2}$).

Third, I don't think I want a MANOVA, as I don't want to know what the effect of $X$ on $Y_{1}$ and $Y_{2}$ (linearly combined) is. I want to know how the two correlation differ.

I seem to want a semi-partial correlation in which the variance shared by $Y_{1}$ and $Y_{2}$ is shared. So, it seems that I should compute residuals for both $Y_{1}$ and $Y_{2}$. To do this, I'll regress $Y_{1}$ on $Y_{2}$ to save the residuals for $Y_{1}$ ($Y_{1}^{*}$), and vice versa for $Y_{2}$ ($Y_{2}^{*}$). Then, the correlation between $X$ and $Y_{1}^{*}$ will be the correlation between $X$ and $Y_{1}$ controlling for the variance shared between $Y_{1}$ and $Y_{2}$; vice versa for $X$ and $Y_{2}$.

My questions:

1. Is this right?
2. Is there a simple way to do this in a statistical package, or do I have to compute the residuals first, then run my correlational or regression analysis with $X$?
3. How do I  compare the effects of $X$ in $Y_{1}$ v. $Y_{2}$? If I just run two correlational analyses ($X-Y_{1}^{*}$ and $X-Y_{2}^{*}$), I can just do an r-to-Z test. But what if I run regressions instead? Can I compare betas in this case?

Comment: Would you be willing to share some more details about the variables? What are you measuring?

Comment: Sorry, I misread. I will rework my answer.

Comment: @noumenal Sure. X is an affective measure. Y1 and Y2 are two different measures of two different kinds of social cohesion: they are conceptually distinct, but empirically correlated.

Comment: Hey Jon. I'm sorry. It took me a while to figure out what your problem was. Have a look at my updated answer! :)

Comment: Were you able to find a solution? What about my final answer...

Comment: Not yet. I'm not very familiar with R, but I'm going to show your answer to someone who is.

Answer (score 1):

When you have multiple dependent variables the solution is to use **set correlation*** (SC), canonical correlation analysis, or MANOVA. The SC is a generalization of both correlation analysis and MANOVA (Cohen et al., 2003). “Set correlation is the amount of shared variance ($R^2$) between two sets of variables” ([Revelle, n.d.](http://personality-project.org/r/html/set.cor.html))

It involves three metrics of trace correlations: multivariate $R^2$, symmetric $T^2$, and asymmetric $P^2$. Symmetry refers to the relationship

$$R^2_{X, Y} = R^2_{Y, X}$$

Asymmetry refers to the situation when a variable is added to either side and a decrease in the correlation can be observed. $R^2_{Y, X}$ reflects the generalized variance of set Y accounted for by set X (Cohen et al., 2003).

To compute the set correlation use the ***R*** package [`psych`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/psych/psych.pdf)

For the determinants of the correlation matrices:

$$R^2_{Y,X}=1-|R_{Y,X}|/(|R_Y||R_X|)$$

(eq. 16.2.1, p.610, Cohen et al., 2003)

This equation shows that unity minus the shared variance will give you an indication of how much of the variance is not shared.

---

Notes


<sub>As I finally arrived at work where I have my reference books, I was able to find an answer to your question. It should be noted that this is a fairly advanced approach - it can be found in the final, 16th, and last chapter of Applied Multiple Regression/Correlation Analysis for the Behavioral Sciences (Cohen, Cohen, West, & Aiken, 2003. Mahwah, NJ: Lawrence Erlbaum.) with the first author having introduced it himself in 1982. See:</sub>

<sub>Cohen, J. (1982). Set correlation as a general mulitivariate data-analytic method. *Multivariate Behavioral Research, 17*(3):301-341.</sub>

<sub>*Care should be taken to avoid Type I errors, of which the likelihood increases with multiple tests (i.e. sets).</sub>

Comment: I don't really see how mod/med helps me here. It's definitely not mediation. Nor is it really moderation: I'm not looking for an interaction between two IVs. Could you please clarify? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much. To clarify: does a step-wise regression control for the variance shared between Y2 (now treated as an IV in the analysis) and Y1, or (like multiple regression more generally), the variance shared between X and Y1? I don't want the latter.

Comment: In step-wise regression, for each variable a t-test is computed, so yes. (For the entire model an F-test is computed.) Using the Enter method you start out with a simple linear regression and in the next steps you have linear multiple regression models - in your case only one additional model. The outcome of the t-test will tell you if the second variable adds anything to explaining the variance. (Y is always dependent on X. If you have multiple outcomes you need multivariable analysis.) Residuals diagnose heterogeneity and autocorrelations, but a first step is to observe the scatter plots.

Comment: Hm. That sounds like step-wise regression controls for the shared variance between Y2 and X (i.e., if X adds anything to Y2 in predicting Y). That's not what I want. I want to control for the shared variance between Y1 and Y2. Multivariate regression combines Y1 and Y2, accounting for the correlation between Y1 and Y2. This isn't what I want either, because I want to tease Y1 and Y2 apart, not combine them together.

Comment: @Jon Your notation is confusing. Y depends always on X. `Y1 = a * x1 + e`.
`Y2 = a * x1 + b * x2 + e`. If `R2(Y1) - R2(Y2) = 0` then `Y1` and `Y2` share variance.

Comment: Well, yes. However, given two DVs, Y1 and Y2, it is feasible that X predicts Y1 but not Y2, even when Y1 and Y2 are moderately correlated. This is basically my question: Does X predict Y1 but not Y2? I don't just want to run two correlational or regression analyses, because Y1 and Y2 share variance. I want to account for this correlation between the two DVs in some way.

Comment: Ah, I think we're getting closer, but I might be a bit confused: in your example, we seem to have 2 IVs and 1 DV. The two DVs are berry type (categorical) and sunshine received (continuous), where these are not independent, because different berries receive different sunlight (because they are of different size). Then your implied DV is the effect of the sunshine on the berries (as you pose it "which of the two berries was more influenced by the sunshine"). But this is disanalogous to my case, where I have one continuous IV, and two correlated continuous DVs, and no categorical variables.

Comment: The previous comment got too long. Your question has me thinking: maybe I should create a dummy variable that has a code for Y1 and Y2, and put *that* in a regression, and run a within subjects analysis. So, I pretend that I only have one DV. The problem with this is the one you allude to: I might need to standardise scores somehow. Also, I'm not sure if this method controls for the shared variance between the two DVs. By the way, do you disagree with my proposed solution, which is to find the residuals for Y1 (regressed on Y2) and Y2 (regressed on Y1) before regressing these residuals on X?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure anymore. The idea was to treat Test as a categorical variable. Perhaps the [Item-total correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Item-total_correlation) would be more informative in your case.

Comment: Updated question. If you are using SPSS you can use the Aggregate function to compute the means.

Comment: Yes, using test as repeated measures variable might work. I'll have to think about how to make the two scores directly comparable first. But you don't have an assessment of my idea about computing Y1 and Y2 residuals (after regressing with Y2 and Y1 respectively) prior to analysis?

Comment: The residuals explain the left-over variance that would be required for a perfect correlation. If another variable is able to "describe" this variance, this could be due to a spurious correlation and does not serve as an explanation.

Comment: The residuals of Y2 (after regression with Y1; let's call this Y2*) is the variance that is not accounted for by Y1, right? So, isn't the correlation of X and Y2 the relationship between X and Y2, controlling for the variance shared by Y2 and Y1? This is just a semipartial correlation, as in multiple regression, where it is the variance shared by X and Y1 that is being controlled for.

Comment: Hi Jon, sorry for the delay. Looking at the residuals sounds convoluted to me. My final thoughts and instructions in the new answer.